# How do I list the contents of a directory with Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I would like to list all the contents of a directory (on the file system) using Dart. How can I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The API has changed and I have updated the async code for M4 release (0.5.16_r23799 ):

```dart
Future<List<FileSystemEntity>> dirContents(Directory dir) {
  var files = <FileSystemEntity>[];
  var completer = Completer<List<FileSystemEntity>>();
  var lister = dir.list(recursive: false);
  lister.listen ( 
      (file) => files.add(file),
      // should also register onError
      onDone:   () => completer.complete(files)
      );
  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: You still need to get the file and directory names, which is surprisingly difficult. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551088/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-a-file-in-dart.

Comment: [From Dart docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-io/FileSystemEntity-class.html): `FileSystemEntity` is superclass to `File`, `Directory` and `Link`.

Comment: How to filter with extension?

Answer (score 72):

### How to list the contents of a directory in Dart

```dart
final dir = Directory('path/to/directory');
final List<FileSystemEntity> entities = await dir.list().toList();
```

This creates a Directory from a path. Then it converts it to a list of `FileSystemEntity`, which can be a `File`, a `Directory`, or a `Link`. By default subdirectories are not listed recursively.

If you want to print that list, then add this line:

```dart
entities.forEach(print);
```

If you want to only get the files then you could do it like so:

```dart
final Iterable<File> files = entities.whereType<File>();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The ones above are either out of date in API and/or Dart style, or unnecessarily complex.

Comment: if you want to filter only files, then you use `element as file` or there is a better way ? ( where `element` is any element in the list that you called `files` )

Comment: @HaidarMehsen, I've updated my answer with one possible solution. I'm not sure if it is the best one but it seems to work.

Answer (score 22):

The `list` method returns a `Stream` where each emitted event is a directory entry:

```
Directory dir = Directory('.');
// execute an action on each entry
dir.list(recursive: false).forEach((f) {
  print(f);
});
```

As the name suggest, `listSync` method is the blocking version:

```
// create a list of entries
List<FileSystemEntity> entries = dir.listSync(recursive: false).toList();
```

What method to use depends on application context. A note directly from the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/Directory-class.html):

> Unless you have a specific reason for using the synchronous version of a method, prefer the asynchronous version to avoid blocking your program.

Comment: May be worth noting that with `Stream.forEach()` the result can be surprising if the callback function is marked `async`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59549511/3558355.

Answer (score 14):

## This answer is out of date. Please see the accepted answer.

There are two ways to list the contents of a directory using the Dart VM and the `dart:io` library.

(note: the following only works in the Dart VM when running on the command-line or as a server-side app. This does not work in a browser or when compiled to JavaScript.)

### Setup

First, you need to import the `dart:io` library. This library contains the classes required to access files, directories, and more.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
```

Second, create a new instance of the `Directory` class.

```dart
var dir = new Directory('path/to/my/dir');
```

### Listing contents in a script

The easiest way is to use the new `listSync` method. This returns a List of contents. By default this does not recurse.

```dart
List contents = dir.listSync();
for (var fileOrDir in contents) {
  if (fileOrDir is File) {
    print(fileOrDir.name);
  } else if (fileOrDir is Directory) {
    print(fileOrDir.path);
  }
}
```

If you want to recurse through directories, you can use the optional parameter `recursive`.

```dart
List allContents = dir.listSync(recursive: true);
```

**WARNING** if your directory structure has circular symlinks, the above code will crash because it's following symlinks recursively.

This method, using `listSync`, is especially useful when you are writing a shell script, command-line utility, or similar app or script with Dart.

### Listing contents in a server

A second way to list the contents of a directory is to use the async version of `list`. You would use this second method when you need to list a directory in response to, say, an HTTP request. Remember that each of Dart's isolates runs in a single thread. Any long running process can block the event loop. When interactivity is important, or serving lots of clients from a single Dart script, use the async version.

With the async version, `dir.list()` returns a `DirectoryLister`. You can register three different callbacks on DirectoryLister:

- `onFile`: called when a file or directory is encountered
- `onDone`: called when the directory lister is done listing contents
- `onError`: called when the lister encounters some error

Here is a simple function that returns a Future of a list of strings, containing file names in a directory:

```dart
Future<List<String>> dirContents(Directory dir) {
  var filenames = <String>[];
  var completer = new Completer();
  var lister = dir.list();
  lister.onFile = (filename) => filenames.add(filename);
  // should also register onError
  lister.onDone = (_) => completer.complete(filenames);
  return completer.future;
}
```

Of course, this method is perfect for servers, it's more cumbersome for simple scripts.

Luckily, Dart supports both methods for you to use!

Answer (score 6):

Inside and asynchronous function write this

```dart
List<FileSystemEntity> allContents = await Directory("folder/path").list().toList();
```

Now you have a list with all of the contents

Comment: This answer adds basically nothing to the question. Everything was written already in previous answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my version using async/await, returning a List of Files only:

```
List<File> filesInDirectory(Directory dir) async {
  List<File> files = <File>[];
  await for (FileSystemEntity entity in dir.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)) {
    FileSystemEntityType type = await FileSystemEntity.type(entity.path);
    if (type == FileSystemEntityType.FILE) {
      files.add(entity);
      print(entity.path);
    }
  }
  return files;
}
```

Comment: 'FILE' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 3):

With this function you can print all the directories and files of a directory.
You just need to pass a specific path.

```
Future listDir(String folderPath) async {
  var directory = new Directory(folderPath);
  print(directory);

  var exists = await directory.exists();
  if (exists) {
    print("exits");

    directory
      .list(recursive: true, followLinks: false)
      .listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
        print(entity.path);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. This is more clear and readable. Is it necessary to add the **async** keyword? Is it not implicit when you make the function return type **Future**?

Comment: The async keyword converts the declared field into a future so the return type of the function can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for this it really works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of file names with a certain string, you can use this code:

```
String directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
List<FileSystemEntity> files = Directory(directory).listSync(recursive: false);

List<String> filePaths = [];
for (var fileSystemEntity in files) {
  if (basename(fileSystemEntity.path).contains('mystring')) {
    filePaths.add(fileSystemEntity.path);
  }
}
```

You can use the basename function if you need just the file name, and not the whole path.

Answer (score 1):

To get all files with **given extension**:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

Future<List<File>> getAllFilesWithExtension(String path, String extension) async {
  final List<FileSystemEntity> entities = await Directory(path).list().toList();
  return entities.whereType<File>().where((element) => p.extension(element.path) == extension).toList();
}
```