# Dart directory scan and list population

Tags: dart

I'm new to this dart stuff and having problems with creating a list with file names from a directory. The example code makes sense but doesn't work and provides no error messages.

I'm really not enjoying how Dart complicates simple tasks.

```dart
var flist = new List();
Process.run('cmd', ['/c', 'dir *.txt /b']).then((ProcessResult results) {
 flist.add(results.toString());
});
```

i know it's way off.. how do i go about this without having to call any outside voids.. i'd like to keep my code in the 'main' function.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this answer useful. It shows how to use the Directory object to list contents of a directory: [How do I list the contents of a directory with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268967/how-do-i-list-the-contents-of-a-directory-with-dart)

Looks like you're trying to find all files in a directory that end in *.txt. You could do this:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  var dir = new Directory('some directory');
  var contents = dir.listSync();
  var textFiles = contents.filter((f) => f.name.endsWith('.txt'));
}
```