# How can I get the name of a file in Dart?

Tags: file, dart

I found I can't get the name of a file in a simple way :(

Dart code:

```dart
File file = new File("/dev/dart/work/hello/app.dart");
```

How to get the file name `app.dart`?

I don't find an API for this, so what I do is:

```dart
var path = file.path;
var filename = path.split("/").last;
```

Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: I think `File` should have an API of `.name`.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use the [path package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path) :

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

main() {
  File file = new File("/dev/dart/work/hello/app.dart");
  String filename = basename(file.path);
}
```

Comment: It may be worth clarifying that you could directly call basename("/dev/dart/work/hello/app.dart") without constructing a new File object and retrieving its path.

Answer (score 57):

If you don't want to use the path pub package, you can use the Uri class from dart:io that returns the filename and its extension:

```
String fileName = File(localFilePath).uri.pathSegments.last;
```

Comment: This is clearly a better answer because it uses the built-in functionality and doesn't spill your global namespace with random unused variables.

Comment: Especially useful if you already have a `Uri` object.

Answer (score 10):

Since Dart Version `2.6` has been announced and it's available for flutter version `1.12` and higher, You can use `extension` methods. It will provide a more readable and global solution to this problem.

`file_extensions.dart` :

```
import 'dart:io';

extension FileExtention on FileSystemEntity{
  String get name {
    return this?.path?.split("/")?.last;
  }
}
```

and `name` getter is added to all the file objects. You can simply just call `name` on any file.

```
main() {
  File file = new File("/dev/dart/work/hello/app.dart");
  print(file.name);
}
```

Read the [document](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) for more information.

**Note:**
Since `extension` is a new feature, it's not fully integrated into IDEs yet and it may not be recognized automatically. You have to import your `extension` manually wherever you need that. Just make sure the extension file is imported:

```
import 'package:<your_extention_path>/file_extentions.dart';
```

Comment: Avoid using the platform dependent `"/"` path separator. Use `Platform.pathSeparator` instead.

Answer (score 6):

*Works as of April, 2020*

- Short and Simple, No external plugin/packages required.
- Copy paste all code and test [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dart)

```dart
void main() {
  var completePath = "/dev/dart/work/hello/app.dart";
  var fileName = (completePath.split('/').last);
  var filePath = completePath.replaceAll("/$fileName", '');
  print(fileName);
  print(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Avoid using the platform dependent `"/"` path separator. Use `Platform.pathSeparator` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new `Path` object from the file's path, and use its `filename` property to get the name of the file:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var file = new File('/dev/dart/work/hello/app.dart');
  Path path = new Path(file.path);
  print(path.filename);      // 'app.dart'
  print(path.directoryPath); // '/dev/dart/work/hello'
}
```

Comment: Quote from Anders Johnsen : `Path` is now deprecated, will be removed at the 11th of August. - see http://dartbug.com/11666

Comment: Alexandre is correct. The Pathos package will be the way to go in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
String url=  https://s3tytf.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com/case-ordersd/2/11/1/215/ODHC01jghf0113592015/oVz058q2ZLjkjghvDVEITM0Vw1G8wexkjI1ENkmZOehgsYNMy1idFYG6otpZoDJKjZU2s.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=0VNN4TZAGM41ULSF&Signature=Wev4LVOoqjLd1W8I1XBdOnE%3D&Expires=1632993368876
```

Now let's say if I just wanna the name of the pdf from the URL with Query String **oVz058q2ZLjDVEITM0Vw1G8wexkjI1ENkmZOehgsYNMy1idFYG6otpZoDJKjZU2s.pdf** so,

```
String pdfName = Uri.parse(url).path.split("/").last
```

Answer (score 1):

The addition for @Alexandre Ardhuin 's answer. The docs from [path](https://pub.dev/packages/path) lib:

```dart
/// Gets the part of [path] after the last separator.
///
///     p.basename('path/to/foo.dart'); // -> 'foo.dart'
///     p.basename('path/to');          // -> 'to'
///
/// Trailing separators are ignored.
///
///     p.basename('path/to/'); // -> 'to'
String basename(String path) => context.basename(path);

/// Gets the part of [path] after the last separator, and without any trailing
/// file extension.
///
///     p.basenameWithoutExtension('path/to/foo.dart'); // -> 'foo'
///
/// Trailing separators are ignored.
///
///     p.basenameWithoutExtension('path/to/foo.dart/'); // -> 'foo'
String basenameWithoutExtension(String path) =>
    context.basenameWithoutExtension(path);
```

So, lets try with `basenameWithoutExtension` function

Answer (score 0):

if you read from assets

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';


void main() async {
  assetsGenerator();
}

void assetsGenerator({String assetsDir='/assets/images/'}) async {
  var assetsPaths = Directory(Directory.current.path + assetsDir);
  try {
    var assetsList = assetsPaths.list();
    await assetsList.forEach((element) {
      String imageName = element.path.split('/').last;
      String imagePath = assetsDir.split('/')[1] +
          '/' +
          assetsDir.split('/')[2] +
          '/' +
          imageName;
      print(imagePath);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    print(error.toString());
  }
}
```

result

```
assets/images/pexels-photo-2102416.jpeg
assets/images/pexels-photo.jpeg
assets/images/pexels-photo-7988087.jpeg
assets/images/pexels-photo-5052877.jpeg
assets/images/pexels-photo-326501.jpeg
assets/images/imac-apple-mockup-app-38544.jpeg
```

get image name in print `imageName` variable

```
imac-apple-mockup-app-38544.jpeg
```