# Get the list of files from directory

Tags: dart

I am trying to add the content of directory using this approach and asign it to List but not sure why it's not working. I see it's async problem but not sure how to solve it.I expect to return the list of files from retCont() but instead it's returning empty list.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  print('CONT: ${await retCont()}');
}

Future retCont() async {
  var myDir = Directory.current;
  List cont = [];
  await myDir.list().listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
    print(entity.path);
    cont.add(entity.path);
  });
  return cont;
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17081903/5362583

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list the contents of a directory with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268967/how-do-i-list-the-contents-of-a-directory-with-dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listen()` returns a `StreamSubscription<FileSystemEntity>` which is not a `Future` so you cannot `await` on that.

The `list()` call returns `Stream<FileSystemEntity>`. For streams you can instead of `await` and `listen()` use `await for` like this:

```
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  print('CONT: ${await retCont()}');
}

Future<List<String>> retCont() async {
  final myDir = Directory.current;
  final cont = <String>[];
  
  await for (final entity in myDir.list()) {
    print(entity.path);
    cont.add(entity.path);
  }
  
  return cont;
}
```

And as a bonus fact, the same program can be written like this if you skip the `print(entity.path);`.

```
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  print('CONT: ${await retCont()}');
}

Future<List<String>> retCont() =>
    Directory.current.list().map((event) => event.path).toList();
```

If you really want to use `StreamSubscription` I think the easiest way is to use a `Completer` instance which you can complete when you have got all the elements from `List()`:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  print('CONT: ${await retCont()}');
}

Future<List<String>> retCont() {
  final myDir = Directory.current;
  final cont = <String>[];
  final completer = Completer<List<String>>();

  myDir.list().listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
    print(entity.path);
    cont.add(entity.path);
  }, onDone: () => completer.complete(cont));

  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: If you are adding all the data of a stream into a list imo in this case it's just better to use: `var list = await myDir.list().toList();`

Comment: @julemand101 thank you for your answer . Can we achieve the same result using StreamSubscription ??? If so could you provide any example please

Comment: Added example of using `StreamSubscription`.

Comment: If you don't use the `StreamSubscription`, you should most likely not use `listen` at all, but use `forEach` instead. In this case: `return myDir.list().forEach((entity) { cont.add(entity.path); }).then((_) => cont);` -- no completer needed. Or maybe `return myDir.list().fold<List<String>>([], (list, entity) => list..add(entity.path));`.