# Get the file and directory names in a directory

Tags: dart

How can I get the file names and directory names in a directory using Dart? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268967/how-do-i-list-the-contents-of-a-directory-with-dart) shows how to get the absolute paths but I only want the actual file/directory names. This code gives absolute paths:

```dart
Directory('/').list().map((entry) => entry.path).toList();
```

Is there a way **other than parsing `entry.path`** to just get the last component of the path? I would have thought the [`FileSystemEntity`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-io/FileSystemEntity-class.html) had a `name` field but it doesn't. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can map the `entry.uri` and then get the last segment of it:

```
  final files = Directory('/')
      .listSync()
      .map((e) => e.uri.pathSegments.last)
      .toList();
  print(files);
```

Comment: Hmm interesting idea. I went with `p.basename(e.path)` from the `path` package, which despite being an external package seems to be the official solution.