# Dart/Flutter - list all folders within a directory

Tags: flutter, dart

First of all, I am new to programming and am trying to learn/motivate myself by approaching programming through projects i.e., I am not learning bottom up and am lacking a lot of skills many of you have...

To the problem: I am trying to get a list of all folders in a folder in my assets directory.

I have tried an answer from [How do I list the contents of a directory with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268967/how-do-i-list-the-contents-of-a-directory-with-dart), but have failed to succeed:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  final dir = Directory('assets/images/');
  final List<FileSystemEntity> entities = await dir.list().toList();
  final Iterable<File> files = entities.whereType<File>();

  for (var file in files) {
    print('File found: ${file.uri.pathSegments.last}');
  }
}
```

I have added the following in the yaml file:

```
flutter:

  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

I get `E/flutter (14446): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathNotFoundException: Directory listing failed, path = 'assets/images/' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`

Thank you in advance!

All the best

Comment: did you provide path to the assets in the pubspec.yaml?
https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images

Comment: I have just added this information. Is what I have provided in the yaml correct?
It states that "Only files located directly in the directory are included. Resolution-aware asset image variants are the only exception. To add files located in subdirectories, create an entry per directory." Does this mean I have to add every single folder in order to be able to access it?

Comment: Are you trying to run this code i a flutter app or just a dart file? If it is just a dart file then you wouldn't need a yaml file and if you are running a flutter app then you need to include you logic inside a widget and run that to print to console.

Comment: It is supposed to run in a flutter app. Can you point me in direction of what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach would work while using just dart but not in a flutter app.

For listing all the paths in asset/images you need to show all the paths using `rootBundle`.

**EXAMPLE**:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  printAssets();
}

void printAssets() async{
  final manifestContent = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');

  final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);

  final imagePaths = manifestMap.keys
      .where((String key) => key.contains('images/'))
      .toList();

  for(var path in imagePaths){
    print('File found: $path');
  }
}
```

For folders you can maipulate the paths using regex:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  printAssets();
}

void printAssets() async{
  final manifestContent = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');

  final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);

  final imagePaths = manifestMap.keys
      .where((String key) => key.contains('images/'))
      .toList();

  final pathList = [];

  for (var path in imagePaths) {
    String finalPath = path
        .replaceAll('assets/images/', '')
        .replaceAll(RegExp(r'[a-zA-z]*.[a-zA-z0-9]{3,4}$'), '');
    if (finalPath.length > 1 && !pathList.contains(finalPath)) {
      pathList.add(finalPath);
    }
  }

  for (var path in pathList) {
    print('Directory Found: $path');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful already and it does list all the images that are in there. But what I want to achieve is a list of all the folders in the given directory. assets/images/ contains three folders "1", "2", "3". I want a list with the names of those three folders. What would need to be changed in order to achieve that?

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter, assets are bundled with the application when compiled. So you can use the rootBundle access files in your assets folder.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  getImagePaths();
}

void getImagePaths() async {
  final manifestContent = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');
  final Map<String, dynamic> manifest = json.decode(manifestContent);
  final imagePaths = manifest.keys
      .where((String key) => key.startsWith('assets/images/'))
      .toList();

  for (var path in imagePaths) {
    print('File found: $path');
  }
}
```

Make sure to call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` first line in main.

Comment: Thank you! This answer is identical to the other one, but you posted it first so I reckon we should continue the discussion here!

Comment: This is really helpful already and it does list all the images that are in there. But what I want to achieve is a list of all the folders in the given directory. assets/images/ contains three folders "1", "2", "3". I want a list with the names of those three folders. What would need to be changed in order to achieve that?

Comment: You can use something like,
print('Folder found: ${path.replaceAll("assets/images/", "").split("/")[0]}');

Comment: So I get 
I/flutter (19485): File found: assets/images/test1.png
I/flutter (19485): File found: assets/images/test2.png
I/flutter (19485): File found: assets/images/test3.png
for you initial code, but
I/flutter (19611): Folder found: test1.png
I/flutter (19611): Folder found: test2.png
I/flutter (19611): Folder found: test3.png
for the version you suggested. However, what I would like to have is 
Folder found: 1
Folder found: 2
Folder found: 3
as those are the names of the folders in the directors assets/images/

Comment: assets/images/test3.png does not mean folder 3. 
assets/images/3/test.png means folder 3.

Comment: Let me rephrase it. Currently the app gives me the path to a picture or the name of a picture. What I would like to have is the different directories that lie within the initially provided path "assets/images/" instead of the pictures that lie there.

Comment: Now that I have worked on it a bit more I understand what you meant earlier. Although this is not exactly what I was looking for, it did get me to a solution! Should I post it here in the comments or make another answer where I kind of answer my own question?